# Llamar función desde componente hijo - Vue

Tags: vue.js

Amigos, tengo un componente padre que con un botón llama una ventana modal en otro componente (hijo), esto lo hice por q el código ya estaba ilejible, este componente hijo mediante un form hace un post con axios a una api que monte con Django, hasta aquí todo bn.
La pregunta es.. ¿?
Cómo llamar una función del componente padre desde el componente hijo cuando el post de axios sea exitoso?

Pd: vengo de MVC .net y apenas estoy aprendiendo vue

Comment: no puse el código porque toy en el celu, gracias a Francisco su respuesta me dio solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `$emit('llamarFuncion')` en el componente hijo y recogiéndolo en el padre con `v-on:llamarFuncion="funcionALlamar"`.

Componente hijo:

```
<template>
    <div class="hijo" v-on:click="$emit('llamarFuncion')"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  name: 'hijo',
</script>
```

Componente padre:

```
<template>
    <div class="padre">
        <hijo v-on:llamarFuncion="funcionALlamar" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  name: 'padre',
  methods: {
    funcionALlamar() {

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Claramente seria más fácil ponerte un ejemplo si nos aportases el código.

Comment: Francisco Garrido, gran aporte amigo me solucionó el problema

Comment: como se hace esto para hacer lo contrario, llamar una funcion desde el componente padre al componente hijo?